# vim:search and replace a word in line beginning with a particular string

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace a particular word in a file, the word appears in many places and I am interested in replacing it on lines beginning or having a particular word. 
For example (ignore grammar)

```
All roads lead to Rome.
Be Roman in Rome.
Where are these roads in Rome.
```

I' am trying to do something like `%s/roads.*Rome/roads.*Italy` 
All lines containing roads and Rome should change the word Rome to Italy.
The second line should be unaltered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a backreference:

```
%s/\(roads.*\)Rome/\1Italy/
```

Alternatively, say:

```
g/roads/s/Rome/Italy
```

(i.e. match lines containing `roads` and substitute `Rome` for `Italy`.  This approach doesn't rely on the order in which the words appear in the line.)

Comment: You could also use `\zs`. For instance, `%s/roads.*\zsRome/Italy/g`